# venv directory in each PyCharm project

Tags: python, pycharm

Is it OK that each of my PyCharm project has a venv directory?

I don't think so.

How can I shadow/replace this directory?

[image]

P.S. PyCharm Professional 2018.1.3, python 3.6

Comment: Yes, it's OK.  Best practice, even.

Comment: As @wim said, it's considered best practise - especially when distributing your project or collaborating, it allows you to replicate your Python environment somewhere else more easily. See [Virtual Environments — The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](https://python-guide-cn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs.html) for more info.

Comment: Does it mean that I should upload this directory to githab?

Comment: Absolutely not.  You should git ignore it.